# Change Line Ending on File in GitHub Repo

Tags: github, line-endings

GitHub supports [Adding a file to a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/adding-a-file-to-a-repository). How can the line endings be changed on an existing file in the repo with the GitHub gui?

This is for an existing file in repo without cloning repo and changing it in git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GitHub documentation about "**[Configuring Git to handle line endings](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings)**" only mentions a *local* Git setting.

That being said, if you can open your project in a [GitHub Web IDE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-web-ide/adjiklnjodbiaioggfpbpkhbfcnhgkfe) (or a [`github.dev` web-based editor](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/the-githubdev-web-based-editor)), then you could change the EOL of a file.

[image]

However... that would be still cloning the repository (on an Azure VM generated for [`github.dev/github/dev`](https://github.dev/github/dev) to use).